# Individual tags aren't clickable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

With the old system when viewing multiple tags you could click on one to only see the questions for that tag. With the new filter, tags aren't clickable at all:

[image: Example]

All I get is a default text cursor and the ability to highlight the tag text:

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been completed and deployed with new nav alpha 2.